# How do I tell what account for Truffle to use when testing contracts?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-config

I'm using Truffle together with Parity to test contracts.

How do I tell truffle what account to use with Parity when testing contracts? I have a total of 3 accounts in Parity currently.

The command I'm currently using is as follows:

```
truffle test --network kovan
```

Answer (score 1):

in the configuration file of truffle (truffle.js), in the networks group, you can specify a `from` field with an address, which is going to be used by default when sending transactions on that network. For example I have this entry for Rinkeby:

```
rinkeby: {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 8545,
  network_id: 4,
  from: "0xaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", // your address here
  gas: 4612388
}
```

Also when running the test whenever you send a transaction you can specify the address of the source explicitly as with any other transaction.